# convert np.nan into value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b = np.where (a==3,np.nan,a)
print (b) #OK, can convert certain values (e.g. 3) into np.nan

c = np.where (b==np.nan,3,b)

print (c)
```

But does not work! Could not convert `np.nan` into 3.
How can  I convert `np.nan` in the array `c` into the value 3?
The result (array `c`) should be same as the original array `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c = np.where(np.isnan(b), 3, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Working with `nan` is a little tricky because `nan != nan`.  You could use `np.isnan` and boolean indexing, though:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10.0)
>>> a
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
>>> a[a % 3 == 0] = np.nan
>>> a
array([ nan,   1.,   2.,  nan,   4.,   5.,  nan,   7.,   8.,  nan])
>>> a[np.isnan(a)] = 999
>>> a
array([ 999.,    1.,    2.,  999.,    4.,    5.,  999.,    7.,    8.,  999.])
```